# Appending Datatable using sqldataAdapter.Fill

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I am iterating through a loop, the idea being that each time it goes through the loop more rows gets added to the same datatable.  I understood that by using the fill method this would be the case.  However in my code the final datatable is the result of the last loop.  Here is my code:

Calling method

```
        // declare a new new datatable to hold the results of the query
        DataTable dtResults = new DataTable();

        foreach (OrgChartNode node in RadOrgChart1.GetAllNodes())
        {
            Label label1 = (Label)node.GroupItems[0].FindControl("Label1");
            foreach (OrgChartRenderedField rf1 in node.GroupItems[0].RenderedFields)
            {
                if (rf1.Label == "ibl")
                {
                    string[] iblWords = rf1.Text.Split(':');
                    string iblId = iblWords[0].Trim();

                    string[,] sqlParam01 =
                                {
                                    { "@document_id", iblId },
                                    { "@class_id", "123" }
                                };
                    dtResults = Helper.GetDataTablePrime(SQL_Default.SQL_Report, sqlParam01, dtResults);

                }

            }

            RadGrid2.DataSource = dtResults;
            RadGrid2.DataBind();
```

and here is the GetDataTablePrime method:

```
    public static DataTable GetDataTablePrime(string query, string[,] sqlParameters, DataTable dtContents)
    {
        String connString = "Data Source=*********************************";
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            // loop through adding parameters
            for (int i = 0; i <= sqlParameters.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
            {
                adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(sqlParameters[i, 0], sqlParameters[i, 1]));
            }
            adapter.Fill(dtContents);
            conn.Close();
        }
        return dtContents;
    }
```

Does anything look out of place ?

Comment: If you look, the code to prepare everything for that "helper" method is more complicated, more obscure and less precise than using the DB Provider directly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't new up the data adapter on each call to `GetDataTablePrime`. Use the same instance like you do with `dtResults`.

> Edit
>   This answer is wrong. It still works if you new up the data adapter each time:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("foo"));

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                dt = FillIt(dt);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[i][0]);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static DataTable FillIt(DataTable dtin)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlConnection cnxn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT 'bar' AS [foo];", cnxn);
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;

            da.Fill(dtin);
            return dtin;
        }
    }
}
```

But you don't need to return the data table. Its a reference type so you can just fill it.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("foo"));

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                FillIt(dt);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[i][0]);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void FillIt(DataTable dtin)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlConnection cnxn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT 'bar' AS [foo];", cnxn);
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;

            da.Fill(dtin);
        }
    }
}
```

So I don't see anything wrong with your code after all. Must be something not shown.